# get index of a value from list/array in dataweave

Tags: arrays, mule, mule-studio, dataweave, anypoint-studio

I have an array in dataweave lets say

```
[value1,value2,value3,value4]
```

I would like to get the index of my value in array. Suppose if I want to know at which index position 'value2' is present, it should return 2.

```
**code I tried:**

%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%var myArray =[] as :array
---
{
 root: using (myArray = payload.values.*value distinctBy $) {
 (payload.values.*value map{
    position: "needs logic to get position of current value in the myArray created"
  })
}


**input:**
<values>
  <value>value1</value>
  <value>value2</value>
  <value>value3</value>
  <value>value4</value>
  <value>value1</value>
  <value>value3</value>
</values>


expected output:
  <root>
    <position>1<position>
    <position>2<position>
    <position>3<position>
    <position>4<position>
    <position>1<position>
    <position>3<position>
  <root>
```

Comment: Hi, it would be better to show what is your input and what do you like to have in output. This could help give the big picture and found suitable solutions.

Answer (score 2):

WHat about :

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%var myArray =[] as :array
---
{
 root: using (myArray = payload.values.*value distinctBy $) {
    (payload.values.*value map (
        position: $$
    )) }
}
```

This outputs:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <position>0</position>
  <position>1</position>
  <position>2</position>
  <position>3</position>
  <position>4</position>
  <position>5</position>
</root>
```

Comment: apologies, I was not clear in the question earlier....the output shown in question is the expected output.

Comment: but your output doesn't look like its the array indexes?

Comment: yeah... its arrayindex+1 is the value required